# switching between local and prod config using git

Tags: git

I would like to switch configuration (such as DB host, imports and so on) between local dev and prod. which is the best way to use git?

1. `git stash save "message"` (create the local config) and `git stash apply` (to apply)
   PROBLEM how can I revert to prod config?
2. `git commit` (create the local config) and `git cherry-pick --no-commit #HASH`
   reverting is easier

Comment: Don't keep local config in git. Instead keep an example of it in the repo.

Comment: how would you switch between local and production configuration?

Comment: Use a different file in your build process. Maybe hard code it into the build config?